# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment - Unsafe assignment of an `any` value

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint, appinsights

I use app insights library in my angular project. And I use eslint to lint the code which really helps find some weird bugs:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AppInsightsService {
   appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
   constructor() {
      this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({   // ====> HERE
         config: {
            instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
            enableAutoRouteTracking: true
         }
      });
      this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();            // ====> HERE
   }

   logPageView(name?: string, url?: string): void {
      this.appInsights.trackPageView({               // ====> AND HERE
         name,
         uri: url
      });
   }
...
}
```

But lint shows the following errors for the lines where I added comments:

> Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment)

Can someone explain please what's wrong with the `appInsights` field?

Comment: Most likely, it is complaining about a param type of `any` being passed into `new ApplicationInsights()`. It wants the param to be a defined type/interface.

Comment: `ApplicationInsights` has this definition for `constructor(snippet: Snippet)`. Not sure I understand what should I change... Also, same error for `this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();`

Comment: Can you try something like: `const config: Snippet = {...` or `const config = new Snippet(...` and pass that to `new ApplicationInsights(config)`

Comment: I tried but there's no such thing as `Snippet`... :/ I mean I do see it in the definition but TypeScript can't find it.